# Azure Function App documentation using API Management

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions, swagger, azure-api-management

I have created a Azure Function App. The function app connects to a SQL DB and has the following features

1. Return all the records in a table
2. Returns the records based on the column name using the below code

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string loan_id = req.Query["loanid"];
            string loan_amount = req.Query["loanamount"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loan_id)) {
                //Do something when dont give loan id.
            } else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loan_amount)) { 
                //DO something when dont give loan amount.
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("This is a test.");
        }
```

I would like to document the function app using API Management/Swagger. Can you please let me know how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an API management service instance from the portal and add the function endpoint using the open api.

You can follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition) on how to do the same.